# How to get HTML from a beautiful soup object

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have the following bs4 object listing:

```
>>> listing
<div class="listingHeader">
<h2>
....


>>> type(listing)
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

I want to extract the raw html as a string. I've tried:

```
>>> a = listing.contents
>>> type(a)
<type 'list'>
```

So this does not work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Just get the [string representation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#non-pretty-printing):

```
html_content = str(listing)
```

This is a non-prettified version.

If you want a prettified one, use [`prettify()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#pretty-printing) method:

```
html_content = listing.prettify()
```

Comment: Is there a way to turn it into a unicode string I'm getting an error: "WebDriverException: Message: u'missing ; before statement' "

Comment: I was struggling with special characters like umlaut ä,ö,ü. One might want to use `soup.prettify( formatter="html" )` - compare https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters

Comment: I am getting \n\t\r when I type cast tag object to str.